# How to remowe a string up to a specific character (Python/pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the DataFrame:

```
link = [{'name': 'http://website.com/product76tre53932'}, {'name': 'http://website.it/productiee8340'}, {'name': 'http://website.de/productooi7309'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(link)
```

How I can cut values that get the next result, which you can see in the `df['name_2]` column:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWNh9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `urllib.parse` module to parse those URLs.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlsplit
>>>
>>> def create_url(url):
...     r = urlsplit(url)
...     return f"{r.scheme}://{r.netloc}"
...
>>> link = [{'name': 'http://website.com/product76tre53932'}, {'name': 'http://website.it/productiee8340'}, {'name': 'http://website.de/productooi7309'}]
>>>
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(link)
>>> df['new_url'] = df.name.apply(create_url)
>>> df
                                   name             new_url
0  http://website.com/product76tre53932  http://website.com
1      http://website.it/productiee8340   http://website.it
2      http://website.de/productooi7309   http://website.de
>>>
```